# How to calculate atoms of *each* element in a compound

Tags: stoichiometry

I am trying to do the following exercise in a chemistry workbook. I have searched over internet but I couldn't find or understand it.

> How many atoms of each element are found in:
>
> - 5 moles $\ce{H2SO4}$

Now the only confusing thing for me is the 5 moles.

For example lets take $\ce{H2}$ element

> so n=N/Na *-->* n × Na = N *(number of atoms)*
>
> 2 × 1gr/mol H = 2 moles H x 5 moles in the compound = 10 moles
>
> 10 moles $\ce{H2}$ × 6.02 × $10^{23}$ = 60.2 × $10^{23}$ atoms

Or do I do like this?

> 5 moles $\ce{H2}$ × 6.02 × $10^{23}$ = 30.1 × $10^{23}$ atoms

Comment: There is no such element as H2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of the mole as a SI prefix, like 'kilo' or 'mega'. If you have 5k $\ce{H2SO4}$ molecules, you will have 10k hydrogen atoms, not 5k. Just as 'kilo' means '1000', a mole means $6.02 \cdot 10^{23}$ *of something*.

Therefore, the first approach gives the correct answer, but I don't understand what you mean by *1gr/mol*. Grams are out of the picture here.